# Highcharts export with rails and heroku

Tags: heroku, highcharts, phantomjs

We want to export highcharts graphs from our rails backend running on heroku. So far we could not figure out how to do it. First idea is to use phantom.js on the server side.
For the export it would be enough to click a button at the graph and get a new page with the current graph as image. Overall it must be easy to get our graphs into a Powerpoint or PDF.
Because of the privacy policies we cannot use any services which provide website-screenshots or something similar on other servers.

Any ideas?